# What is the difference between AV Media Servers and Streaming Media Systems?

Tags: lan, streaming, media-server

I found two groups of software, concerning transmitting video over LAN.

Both are often referred to as **media servers**.

But groups are not intersected, although, apparently, both provide similar functionality.

My question is: What is the deep distinction between these two groups and why don't they like each other?

Representatives of one group often serves protocols like UPnP and DLNA and roughly is listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers

Representatives of second groups often serves protocols like RTP and RTMP and roughly is listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems

Answer (score 1):

While UPnP and DLNA are only suitable for (and aimed at) closed/home environments, streaming itself (be it HTTP or RTP or whatever) is suitable for any IP network. Every UPnP server (or AV media server) must also be a streaming server. In most cases, HTTP is used, though other protocols are possible.

So, basically: DLNA is your “second group” plus X, where X is, in essence, a management and presentation framework that hides complexity from home users.

Here’s an example screenshot of BubbleUPnP, because browsing DLNA servers is next to impossible “by hand”:

[image]

As you can see, there’s a plain HTTP URL at the bottom. This URL can be used from any PC/device that can reach the media server.

Comment: Can you provide any examples please? For example, having any DLNA server, how is it possible to stream movie over HTTP, so that it possible to view it by, for example VLC player without DLNA option?

Comment: I updated my answer, @Dims. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So, DLNA server is generating normal HTTP stream, but does this out of my control? I.e. I can't stream this movie under http://192.168.2.5:32469/stateoftheunion.mkv even if I want?

Comment: @Dims That’s correct. Some DLNA servers have predictable URLs, but most do not.

Comment: So why is it so? Just microscopic modification will turn one server type into another; but this modification does not happen; why?

Comment: If you want to discuss that, I suggest you go to the chat rooms. This site isn't suitable for it.